# Shopware 6: How to set boolean config values with Docker exec in Git Bash

Tags: bash, docker, git-bash, shopware6, docker-exec

I'm running a Bash script on Windows Git Bash that uses docker exec to set config values in my Shopware container:

```rb
docker exec -d $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID php bin/console system:config:set $PLUGIN_NAME.config.active true
```

But I get an error that the config value must be a boolean, not a string.
It seems passing "true" from Bash sets it as a string, when it needs to be a proper bool value. How can I properly set a boolean config value `true/false` from a Bash script using docker exec?

Comment: This seems like the same issue: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/issues/2207 The issue is closed, but I'm unsure what the solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by using -j (-json) to decode the `true` as a bool.

```rb
docker exec  $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID php bin/console system:config:set -j $PLUGIN_NAME.config.active true
```

Answer (score 2):

There's seems to be a decode option added on this commit
https://github.com/shopware/shopware/pull/2209/commits/e4d49e20248be3e770860297417ef5a87b7fb686#diff-a041d80e81de3a24e5d1b155454509b67b3c5c0d72732b311a00aa47fccefbe1R33

It allows an input value to be interpreted as JSON and therefore be converted to boolean. I believe it can be used like this `--decode` or `-d`

Comment: Thanks for the reply where should I add `--decode` in my command?

Comment: I believe it should work after the whole line like so: `docker exec -d $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID php bin/console system:config:set $PLUGIN_NAME.config.active true --decode`

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: It does not work.